# Symmetric and anti-symmetric systems of polynomial equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Can I present a set of polynomial equations as a sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric systems?

Comment: what do you mean by symmetric and anti-symmetric   system?you mean matrices should be symmetric and  anti-symmetric or polynomials?

Comment: you meant like this?ask please if any question

Comment: I have a set of polynomial equations and I want to split it and I think about the way.

Comment: please post this polynomials

Answer (score 0):

let us consider following equation

$f(x)=x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x$

then we may have it as

$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$

where  $g(x)$ symmetric because

$g(-x)=g(x)$

and $h(x)=-x^5-x^3-x$

$h(-x)=-h(x)$ anti-symmetric polynomial

you mean this one?

of course if there is constant added ,then i think it is impossible or at least difficult,we may consider this constant  as  positive and  should be member of  symmetric polynomial

Comment: For example I have the following system of polynomial equations
$$
f(x)=0, \\
g(x)=0, \\
h(x)=0. \\
$$
I want to split the system on sum of two another systems and may be they have some additional properties (symmetric, anti-symmetric, cyclic, ...)

Comment: it depend on clearly degrees and members of system,i dont know directly answer if there is such  theorem or axiom,but clearly it depend on system, symmetric means $f(-x)=f(x)$ right?antisymmetric $f(-x)=-f(x)$ right?so it depend on system in my mind,try to  give some concrete example and post   this

Comment: My question is general so I don't have a set of equations. I am reading Geometrical algebra course. So my question is how many ways   can we split a set of polynomial equations and is there any way to split a set on sum of another sets of polynomial equations?

Comment: sorry then maybe some expierenced person can help,i just wanted to help,good lcuks